# Page orientation changes when using PdfSharp

Tags: orientation, scaling, pdfsharp

I'm using PdfSharp to crop PDF documents, using the following, simplified example :

```
        using (PdfDocument input = PdfReader.Open(filename, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Modify)) {
            int page_id = 0;
            while (page_id < input.PageCount) {
                PdfPage page = input.Pages[page_id];
                input.Pages.RemoveAt(page_id);

                PdfPage new_page = (PdfPage)page.Clone();
                input.Pages.Insert(page_id++, new_page);
            }

            input.Save(filename);
        }
```

Running this code on a 800*400 pdf file produces a 400*800 pdf file; that is, something gets screwed up with the page orientation, and the resulting pdf doesn't have the same dimensions as the original one

Do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong ? Ideally, the code I provided should produce exactly the same document...

Thanks!

**Note**: Running the same code twice does restore the original orientation.

Comment: May I ask why you don't use `PdfCopy` or `PdfSmartCopy`?

Comment: Yes; my app also deals with pdf metadata, and sticking with one lib sounds simpler.

Comment: I guess you misunderstood me, `PdfCopy` and `PdfSmartCopy` are classes **inside** iText, not other libs :)

Comment: Ooooh, right; do you have examples of how these could be used to crop PDFs then?

Comment: Check these examples for [PdfCopy](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=109) and [PdfSmartCopy](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=125). Instead of altering the original PDF, the idea would be to create copies of it with only the desired pages.

Comment: Errrr, the examples I just gave relate to iTextSharp, since your question was originally tagged with `itextsharp`. Now that you edited the tags and seem to mean that you use PDFSharp, my comments are totally off-topic :(

Comment: Thanks. Though my initial title was misleading, I am now considering moving to iTextSharp given your examples. Thanks for the help, and sorry for hte initial confusion. I've found the problem with PdfSharp -- it was a bug --, and will post the answer as soon as I can reply to my own question.